# .npz file contains different datatypes, how do I plot the images contained within the .npz file?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, file-io

im currently trying to learn Python through a project at the moment, and I have been given an .npz file
containing different datatypes in them; I have explored the data using

```
cell_data = np.load("C:/Users/cell-data.npz")
```

`d = dict(zip(("data:{}".format(k) for k in cell_data), (cell_data[k] for k in cell_data))) print(d)`

Which gives me this as an [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ut5GN.png).

Ive also run `cell_data.files`, telling me that the file contains `['images', 'counts', 'folds', 'compressed', 'allow_pickle']`

How would I retrieve individual images, and plot them? Usually if it was just a single image in an .npz file I would use plt.imshow('thatfile.npz'), but im unsure how to do this when there are multiple files of different datatypes within the .npz.

I have also tried the following:

```
images = cell_data["images"]
counts = cell_data["counts"]
folds = cell_data["folds"]
X0 = images[folds == 0]
Y0 = counts[folds == 0]
plt.imshow(images, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

However this doesnt seem to be working, I experience the error:

```
TypeError: Invalid shape (2351, 256, 256, 3) for image data
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: An `.npz` is a zip archive of `.npy` files.  `load` gives a dict like object.  `cell_data['images']` should load one array.  `cell_data['counts']` loads another.  But that's what you are doing with the `cell_data[k]`.   I'm not sure what's the issue.

Comment: @hpaulj  when I try to run `plt.imshow(cell_data['images'], cmap='gray') plt.show()` it returns an error, as I think its trying to plot all the images within the images array, I would like to know how to retrieve individual picture arrays, within the 'images' array itself, and plot those.

Comment: @hpaulj Ive also edited in another attempt, and the error code it produces, not sure if this helps with my question?

Comment: That shape looks like 2351 images each with shape (256,256) and 3 color channels.  Does `imshow(images[0])` work?

Comment: @hpaulj Yes it does, thank you, appreciate the help!